# PHP Get value of sub array in text box depending upon dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, yii

In my Yii PHP code I have an array as

```
$groups = array(
        GroupA => array(
            a,
            aa,
            aaa,

        ),
        GroupB => array(
            b,
            bb,
            bbb,
        ),
        GroupC => array(
            c,
            cc,
            ccc,
        ),
    );
```

and drop dow having values as -> GroupA, GroupB, GroupC

now when GroupA is selected fill three text box with values a, aa, aaa
and same for all dropdown values.

How to do this?
Please give me a start, I will do rest of this..

Thank you

Comment: because this is a front-end matter, IMHO you have to handle this with javascript, this has nothing to do with php

Comment: Let's pass `GroupA` to an ajax request, search the array key and return the sub array of it in json, and fill the textbox.

Comment: @tinybyte yes you are right, but the reason I go with php is if I need to extend array I am good in managing it with php.

Comment: @lolka_bolka thank you for guiding me... bellow is the answer with same... thanks all for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go mate

```
<?php


    $groups = array(
            'GroupA' => array(
                'a',
                'aa',
                'aaa',

            ),
            'GroupB' => array(
                'b',
                'bb',
                'bbb',
            ),
            'GroupC' => array(
                'c',
                'cc',
               ' ccc',
            ),
        );
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // using JSON.parse with json_encode
    var groups = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($groups) ?>' );


    </script>

    <select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
         <option value="">Select</option>

         <option value="GroupA">GroupA</option>
         <option value="GroupB">GroupB</option>
         <option value="GroupC">GroupC</option>
    </select><br><br>



    TextBox<br>


    <input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="Get value on option select"><br>
    <input type="text" id="srt1" placeholder="Get value on option select"><br>
    <input type="text" id="srt2" placeholder="Get value on option select"><br>




    <script>
    function run() {
     document.getElementById("srt").value =   groups[document.getElementById("Ultra").value][0] ;
      document.getElementById("srt1").value =   groups[document.getElementById("Ultra").value][1] ;
      document.getElementById("srt2").value =   groups[document.getElementById("Ultra").value].valueOf() ;<!--Replace .valueOf() with [2] if you want only the third value aaa,bbb,ccc-->

    }



    </script>
```